# Cannot Renew Apple Developer Membership

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I am trying to renew my Apple developer membership. These are the steps I follow:

```
1. I visit the Member Center
2. I click on Renew Membership
3. Follow the steps until I arrive at the payment page
4. I am automatically redirected to the Member Center home page!
```

Therefore, I can't renew my membership at all. If I try to stop the redirect from happening, I stay on the payment page, but an error appears when I try to make the payment.

See the accompanying video here: https://youtu.be/JtFCZ8bo1wU

Apple seems to have a new Member Center design. Is it possible it may be buggy?

Answer (score 1):

I had to disable auto-renew for the (manual) renewal option to appear. Wanted to make sure no last minute issue with my payment card associated with the apple Id of the developer account.

Comment: How do you disable auto-renew?  I want to discontinue my membership after it expires, but am afraid it will automatically bill me.

Comment: Hey Richard, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57669832/1294832) below!

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter a valid card on you appleid settings. https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just did so, logged out of the Apple ID settings, logged out of the Member Center, logged back in and tried again. Same issue, I'm afraid. :(

Comment: You entered a valid credit card? I solved the issue doing that, let me check other options

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: same problem here... seems they somehow killed the service behind the payment express checkout link...

Answer (score 0):

I had had the same problem! I called by phone to Apple, we checked all information with operator about my account. And found out, that my birthday date is incorrect. Аfter that everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue with the redirect of the page. I contacted Apple Support and the workaround for the issue was to pay with a bank transfer instead of paying through the website. 
Now one year later, the same problem is occurring and I am going to pay with a bank transfer again.

This issue might have something to do with the country where the credit card is issued, maybe Apple does not accept credit cards from all conutries.

Comment: A bit late, but can you elaborate on how you got them to agree to a bank transfer? So far all their emails to me feel like I'm talking to a bot

Comment: I called them, but I didn’t have to pay with a transfer the second time like I was going to do. The call center agent extended my membership for some time so it wouldn’t expire. During the extended time they fixed the credit card thing and it has worked since.

Comment: You could try calling apple in different countries if you can’t reach them in your region. They suggested the transfer solution and also extending the membership to avoid expiry. When you find a person to talk to they will help you to solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you, they indeed aren't available in my country but I will try contacting them by phone.

Answer (score 0):

After updating my date of birth it was launching the renew membership page.I believe apple wont allow if the account holder age is below 18.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to open the Apple Developer Account page in Safari for the "Renew" button to appear at the top of the page.

https://developer.apple.com/account/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to auto-renew your membership, or you have trouble adding a credit card (like I had), you can disable auto-renew in the bottom of the membership area. This will make a new button to renew your membership manually appear. I had to do it a couple of times before the button appeared and it worked not in Safari but only in Chrome...

When you manually renew your membership you can enter a new credit card that will be used only for this payment. This only worked in Chrome and NOT in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

For **non US devs**:

Apparently, if you have your country outside the US your cards will be rejected. As a solution, I updated my address both for my Apple Id and for App store connect (these must be the same) with a US bank account.

This was a manual process that took a couple of days but after this, I could pay and renew my app.

Answer (score 0):

After wasting 4 hours of time, I could finally find this.

Apple made it to manage the payments using iOS Devices -> Account -> Subscription. No way to pay this online using Web as before.

To renew your Apple Developer membership:

1. Make sure you have added a payment method to your Apple ID account.
2. On your iPhone or iPad, open the App Store app and tap on your profile picture in the top right corner.
3. Tap on "Manage Payments" and add a payment method if you don't already have one.
4. Go to Settings > Your Account and tap on your name and email address at the top of the screen.
5. Tap on "Subscriptions".
6. Find your Apple Developer membership in the list of subscriptions and tap on "Edit Subscription".
7. Tap on the "Renew" button to pay for the renewal.

Please note that the steps may vary slightly depending on your device and iOS version.